# How to set default value for the `TypeVar`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

I want to create a create default value for `TypeVar`, so, when not specified, Mypy deduce the default type:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar("T", default=str)  # The default value doesn't work.

class BookCollection(Generic[T]):
    pass

books = BookCollection()  # So, the Mypy deduces T as Any instead of str.
```

I have attempted to use the `bound` parameter of the `TypeVar` but it does not indicate a default value, thus it does not function as intended.

Comment: There is no way to do this. Just do `books = BookCollection[str]()`

Comment: There might be a way in future, though: PEP696 is draft. https://peps.python.org/pep-0696/